# SwiftUI Popup button with Primary action

Tags: swiftui

I am looking for a cross-platform solution where tapping on a button will trigger an action, and on an iOS device, tapping and holding, or on the Mac, right mouse clicking, will display a menu.

The code below works as expected on the iOS but does not show contextual menu on the Mac.

Is there a simple solution? Thanks

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Menu{
            Button("Item One", action: {})
            Button("Item Two", action: {})
            Button("Item Three", action: {})
        } label: {
            Label("Options", systemImage: "paperplane")
        } primaryAction: {
            print("Button was tapped")
        }
        .buttonStyle(.borderless)
    }
}
```

Comment: Context menu and menu are 2 different things

Comment: Thanks, yes using .contextMenu does solve some of the issues, but when menuItems have image, they dont show up in the MacOS and also, is there a way to set the state of the menuItem to on or off?